# How to get citizenship for Ireland through "Critical Skills Employment Permit"?

Tags: visa, citizenship, ireland

There is a Visa type for Ireland titled "Critical Skills Employment Permit".
Presume I've gotten that permit, now questions:

- how can I get a Visa and citizenship if I don't have enough money in my bank account, or don't have a "Strong Family, Social or Economic Tie" and other things that are required to get a Visa?
- How can I get citizenship if for Visa approval they want me to prove that I'll return to my country?

Answer (score 6):

The Critical Skills Employment Permit is for skilled professionals in shortage areas where you have a job offer for at least two years. Requirements for connections to your home country and similar are only relevant for short term visit or study visas, and will not apply here.

That said, this is not a straightforward visa to obtain. There are a number of criteria involving pay, qualifications/experience and the company who hires you. If you can find a company willing to hire you under this scheme, there is a path to residency after five years (not necessarily all with the same company). Citizenship would come after that.

[More details from this official site.](https://dbei.gov.ie/en/What-We-Do/Workplace-and-Skills/Employment-Permits/Permit-Types/Critical-Skills-Employment-Permit/)

Comment: "Residency" is immediate upon arrival (after all, you are living there). Residency independent of the Critical Skills permit is possible after two years. It's applying for citizenship that becomes possible after five years residency.

Comment: "not a straightforward visa to obtain": but the permit and the visa are separate.  The question asks us to assume that the permit has already been granted, and consider the subsequent visa application.  Considering the subsequent visa application separately, it seems like it probably *is* fairly straightforward unless the applicant has a criminal history or something like that, don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

CSEP isn't a visa. It doesn't give you ability to enter or register or live in Ireland. You even cannot get it by self.

You need a sponsor that gives you permanent and highly payed contract. Sponsor applies for CSEP for you. If the sponsor gets CSEP, then you should apply for entry work visa in Irish embassy. If you would be granted the visa, you should enter into the Ireland, start your job and register in Irish Immigration Authority named GNIB. They would give you Stamp 1 status. This day is the first day of your "Strong Family, Social or Economic Tie" in Ireland. You can apply for the citizenship after 5 years right after the day.

However the quest is far from over. You should work for your sponsor at last two continues years in order to get the next Stamp 4 status. Then with the Stamp 4 you should live 3+ years.